# Delete trigger on a AWS Lambda function in python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function and for that lambda function my cloudwatch event is a trigger on it...

at the end of the lambda function i need to delete the trigger (cloud watch event ) on that lambda function programatically using python .

how can i do that ? is there any python library to do that?

Answer (score 3):

The Python library you are looking for is the [AWS SDK for Python](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/), also called Boto3. This library is pre-loaded in the AWS Lambda environment. all you have to do is add `import boto3` to your Lambda function.

I believe you will need to use the [CloudWatchEvents](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/events.html) client and either call `delete_rule()` or `remove_targets()` depending on exactly what you want to do.

Comment: i used remove_targets and delete_rule to completely delete the rule after that too still the reference of the rule is shown on the trigger section of the lambda

Comment: I assume you mean the trigger section of the AWS Lambda web console? Did you refresh the page?

Comment: Are you sure your code ran without errors? Did you get a successful response? Did you check the CloudWatch Events console also?

Comment: yes it deleted the cloud watch rule, but however it is still showing up on the trigger section of the lambda @Mark B

Answer (score 1):

Came across the same issue and found the solution. What you want is `remove_permission()` on the lambda client

Answer (score 0):

I just finished how to remove the EventBridge events which trigger the lambda function.  Below is my code, hope it's helpful

```
import boto3
    
            eventbridge_client = boto3.client('events')
            lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda')
            remove_target = eventbridge_client.remove_targets(
                Rule=rule_Name,
                EventBusName='default',
                Ids=[
                    target_Name,
                ],
                Force=True
            )
            
            remove_rule = eventbridge_client.delete_rule(
                Name=rule_Name,
                EventBusName='default',
                Force=True
            )
            
            remove_invoke_permission = lambda_client.remove_permission(
                FunctionName="arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxx:function:functionTobeTrgiggerArn",
                StatementId=target_permission_Name,    
            )
```

Let me know if you still have questions